# How do I open a folder using the filename directory?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `ListBox` which contains directories and file names which would be shown like this `C:\File.txt`. I would like to open the folder of the selected item using a `ContextMenuStrip` which would be like this

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(ListBox1.SelectedItem) = True Then
    Process.Start(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End If
```

but of course that only opens the file instead of the folder, how would I trim off the filename so it would only open the folder?

Note: `Process.Start("C:\")` wouldn't be a solution for me as there would be many different directories/files within this `ListBox`, so it wouldn't always be the same folder for all the listed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` method. This returns the folder path.

For example:

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\something\file.txt"
Dim folderPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
```

Returns `C:\something`. So modify your code to:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(ListBox1.SelectedItem) = True Then
    Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(ListBox1.SelectedItem))
End If
```